# Running mpstat in GitHub workflow in the background does not work

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to run mpstat command in the background while running some long-running tests on GitHub large runners to see CPU utilization and whether the tests make use of all the cores, but for some reason, the output file is not created and the workflow run fails with a file not found error.
I'm using the code snippet below to achieve this:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Collect Workflow Telemetry
    run: |
      mpstat -P ALL 5 > telemetry.out 2> telemetry.err < /dev/null &
  - uses: ./.github/actions/test
  - name: Cat telemetry
    run: cat ./telemetry.out
```

Any idea what might be the issue here?

Comment: Is this the test script (`uses: ./.github/actions/test`) that you're running?

Comment: The line you highlighted calls a custom action residing in the same repo that runs the long-running tests.

Comment: Right. Did you try to check whether `mpstat` is still running e.g. `ps aux | grep mpstat` before `cat`?

Comment: I just tested this scenario and it's working as expected. Here's the test run: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/3901744259/jobs/6663962885. You can check the raw logs as well.

Comment: Yeah, in my case the issue was that probably our setup works in a different way and only preserver stuff if you create it under $HOME.

Comment: Right. Good to hear that it works with `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the script so it would create the output file under $HOME, it started to work. Looks like GHA creates a working directory for each step.